# Atomic Steampunk

Tags: science-fiction, steampunk, radiation

I know steampunk, or rather, steam and coal technology is very limited, needs lots of space, little portability and little energy use.

[image]

But nuclear plants use the same thing, the only difference is that instead of coal, they use uranium to heat the water to generate temperatures and absurd pressures that move turbines to generate electricity.

[image]

I am aware that radiation is very dangerous and can cause irreparable damage (if you don't die). But WHAT IF a steampunk world didn't find oil to migrate to internal combustion engines and remained in steam and coal until they found uranium?

And well, when the radiation was discovered, numerous radioactive products were put up for sale promising miracles. That radioactive toothpaste promised brighter teeth, for example.

[image]

This could open up to many different kinds of alternative worlds. From societies where the poor work near the nuclear power plants and generations are increasingly deformed and disgusting while the rich remain healthy and untouchable.

Or even a noir plot where the transition from coal to uranium has made unprecedented advancement in technology, but big business owners and governments are trying to hide the imminent danger of unsafe uranium use.

[image]

Well, the thing is, how much would be needed to move a steam train, for example?  Or a steam car? Or even bigger machines?

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding, Neto Ananias! If you have a moment, please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. You may also find [meta] and [The Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6168/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) useful. [Here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6388) is a meta post on the culture and style of Worldbuilding.SE, just to help you understand our scope and methods, and how we do things here. Have fun!

Comment: How do you control a nuclear reactor without electronics?

Comment: Yeah ... Well, at the beginning of the development of nuclear reactors, everything was made with cranks. Was it safe? Certainly not.

There are many details of nuclear power that I didnt take into account, but the idea would be that the amount of uranium would not be enough to make a nuclear power plant work because it would be a minimal amount. Even so, I do not know much about nuclear power.

Comment: This is certainly an interesting idea for a world. But unfortunately there isn't really a well-defined *question* here. Question&answer sites don't work well for open-ended and discussion-oriented brainstorming questions. Can you try to formulate an objectively answerable question about such a world?

Comment: You said that you do not know much about nuclear power. I would really recommend you to do some research in this regard. There is so much stuff from the history of nuclear energy you could use. If you want it to be dark, then the [list of nuclear disasters and accidents on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_nuclear_disasters_and_radioactive_incidents) could provide you with plenty of inspiration for stuff that could go wrong.

Comment: *"Nuclear plants [...] use uranium to heat the water to generate temperatures and absurd pressures":* nuclear power plants actually work with steam at lower temperature (and therefore, lower pressure) than coal or gas-powered thermoelectric plants. And nuclear power plants *do not* produce any increase in radioactivity around them. If you are looking for small nuclear reactors, consider those used on nuclear-powered ships and submarines, or in [floating nuclear power stations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_floating_nuclear_power_station).

Comment: (a) You appear to be asking us to define a new story genre, that's not what we do here.  (b) The SE model is one-specific-question/one-best-answer, you have many questions in that post.  (c) To see how miniature nuclear reactors are used in a story, read Asimov's *[Foundation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foundation_series)* series of books, especially the titular book, *Foundation.*  (d) "Steampunk" is defined as "the future powered by steam."  Powering the future with a nuclear reactor is simply the present.

Comment: You could probably build mechanical nuclear generators using a sterling engine. They'd be quite dangerous though, and not terribly efficient I wouldn't think unless you had access to Plutonium or Strontium-90.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_nuclear_fission_reactor if you go with people first started using steam from steam vents I guess you could go with the analogy that nuclear steampunk would start with naturally occurring reactors.

Comment: Ehm, nuclear power plants are waaaay bigger than the traditional thermoelectric ones...

Comment: I still don't see a focused single-point question here. A lot of interesting background, though.

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out what you are asking. If it is whether Atomic steampunk is possible? The answer is yes as [steampunk is about victorian culture more than technology](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/124088/54517).